# How to scan a website using Nessus with login credentials

Tags: session-management, vulnerability-scanners, credentials, web-scanners, nessus

I have scanned my website using [Nessus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nessus_(software)). But I need to scan it as a logged in user since most of the URLs are accessible only if we are logged in. How can I set website login credentials in Nessus?

Comment: Login mechanisms differs from site to site, can't you just disable the login mechanism or make an auto-login from a certain IP? [Otherwise try your favorite search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=nessus+scan+website+with+credentials)

Comment: I have searched in google before asking here..didn't get solution..'Scaning by login mechanism disabled' seems good idea..Will check that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nessus 5 made a change: It's in the Preferences section:

- Login configurations
- HTTP login page

There you can set your HTTP credentials/settings.

This is a basic check in the [documentation](http://static.tenable.com/documentation/nessus_5.2_HTML5_user_guide.pdf). Why go Google, when you can RTFM....

Answer (score 2):

Nessus has the information posted on their page with a full walk through. http://www.tenable.com/tips/how-to-enable-credentialed-checks-on-windows

Comment: No. It's for log in to the remote host (Remote login) and scan. It's not for  website login.

Comment: Munkeyoto has the right idea, but the wrong section. There's a section for basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- Cookie import: First you have to export them from your browser in netscape format. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992242/how-to-login-to-a-webpage-in-nessus-and-perform-a-sectest)
- Http Login Parameters: 
  An article demonstrating this option is [here](https://www.tenable.com/blog/scanning-web-applications-that-require-authentication).

  Moreover, the steps as described in the [documentation](https://static.tenable.com/documentation/nessus_6.4_user_guide.pdf) are the following:

  1. Create new scan
  2. Web Application Tests
  3. Credentials: which are filled out like these (taken from documentation):

     - Username: Login user’s name.
     - Password: Password of the user specified.
     - Login page: The absolute path to the login page of the application, e.g., /login.html
     - Login submission page: The action parameter for the form method. For example, the login form for:  would be: /login.php
     - Login parameters: Specify the authentication parameters (e.g., login=%USER%&password=%PASS%). If the keywords %USER% and %PASS% are used, they will be substituted with values supplied on the Login configurations drop-down menu. This field can be used to provide more than two parameters if required (e.g., a group name or some other piece of information is required for the authentication process).
     - Check authentication on page: The absolute path of a protected web page that requires authentication, to better assist Nessus in determining authentication status, e.g., /admin.html.
     - Regex to verify successful authentication: A regex pattern to look for on the login page. Simply receiving a 200 response code is not always sufficient to determine session state. Nessus can attempt to match a given string such as Authentication successful

However, in my case (drupal 6), it couldn't authenticate